# Move trough tr in different tables with keys and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to move throught table rows with the up and down arrows. I have this markup:

```
<table border="1">
<tr class="tableIndex highlight">
  <td>Something</td>
  <td>Something</td>
  <td>Something</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tableIndex">
  <td>Something</td>
  <td>Something</td>
  <td>Something</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tableIndex">
  <td>Something</td>
  <td>Something</td>
  <td>Something</td>
</tr>
</table> 
<table border="1">
<tr class="tableIndex">
  <td>Something</td>
  <td>Something</td>
  <td>Something</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tableIndex">
  <td>Something</td>
  <td>Something</td>
  <td>Something</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tableIndex">
  <td>Something</td>
  <td>Something</td>
  <td>Something</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table border="1">
<tr class="tableIndex">
  <td>Something</td>
  <td>Something</td>
  <td>Something</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tableIndex">
  <td>Something</td>
  <td>Something</td>
  <td>Something</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tableIndex">
  <td>Something</td>
  <td>Something</td>
  <td>Something</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And this jQuery JavaScript Code to navigate throught the items:

```
$(function() {
function highlighting(tableIndex,className) {
    // Just a simple check. If .highlight has reached the last, start again
    var $trClass = $('.'+className);
    if( (tableIndex+1) > $trClass.length ) {
      console.log('tableIndex > '+ $trClass.length);
      tableIndex = 0;
    }

    // Element exists?
    if($trClass.eq(tableIndex).length > 0)
    {
      // Remove other highlights
      $trClass.removeClass('highlight');

      // Highlight your target
      $trClass.eq(tableIndex).addClass('highlight');
    }
  }
  $(document).keydown(function (e) {
    //first check if any input has focus
    if($('input:focus').length == 0) {
      switch (e.which) {
        case 38:
          //ARROW UP - move up
          console.log('Current (up): ' + $('.tableIndex').index());
          highlighting(($('.tableIndex.highlight').index() - 1), 'tableIndex');
          break;
        case 40:
          console.log('Current (down): ' + $('.tableIndex').index());
          highlighting(($('.tableIndex.highlight').index() + 1), 'tableIndex');
          break;
      }
    }
  })
  console.log('Total: ' + $('.tableIndex').length);
});
```

This works fine if I only have one table but not when there are multiple tables.
The length of the index is right (like 9 in this example) but the navigation is totally off the charts. Like the first item is -1 and then everything else behaves bonkers. I can navigate through the items 2-4 normally but when I go up on the second item it jumps to the last... I just have no clue why?

I put a jsfiddel together for this here: https://jsfiddle.net/vog54ygo/6/

Comment: Hint: https://jsfiddle.net/vog54ygo/7/ tr indexes goes from 0 to 2 (3 rows per table), in every table...click on rows to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be understanding your requirements incorrectly, but I think you've got an overthought answer.

Is this what you want?

```js
var $rows = $(".tableIndex");
var current = 0;

$(function() {
 
  $(document).keydown(function (e) {
 
      switch (e.which) {
        case 38: //ARROW UP - move up
          if(current > 0){
           $rows[current].setAttribute("class", "");
           $rows[current - 1].setAttribute("class", "highlight");
           current--;
          }
          break;
        case 40:
          if(current <  $rows.length-1){
           $rows[current].setAttribute("class", "");
           $rows[current + 1].setAttribute("class", "highlight");
           current++;
          }
          break;
      }
  });
  

});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
<tr class="tableIndex highlight">
  <td>Something</td>
  <td>Something</td>
  <td>Something</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tableIndex">
  <td>Something</td>
  <td>Something</td>
  <td>Something</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tableIndex">
  <td>Something</td>
  <td>Something</td>
  <td>Something</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table border="1">
<tr class="tableIndex">
  <td>Something</td>
  <td>Something</td>
  <td>Something</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tableIndex">
  <td>Something</td>
  <td>Something</td>
  <td>Something</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tableIndex">
  <td>Something</td>
  <td>Something</td>
  <td>Something</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table border="1">
<tr class="tableIndex">
  <td>Something</td>
  <td>Something</td>
  <td>Something</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tableIndex">
  <td>Something</td>
  <td>Something</td>
  <td>Something</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tableIndex">
  <td>Something</td>
  <td>Something</td>
  <td>Something</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you - that was what I needed. And yeah maybe I was overthinking :) The only think I also needed was to cycle through completly, when I'm at the top jump to last one and vice versa. I put it together here: https://jsfiddle.net/gxhjzff4/